# GoogleMap NullPointerException with targetSdkVersion 21

Tags: android

I'm working on an app which includes a `MapFragment` accessed through a tab. Recently, with the release of Android 5.0 Lollipop, I decided to update for material design. I went through making the necessary changes (Changing SDK in build.gradle, switching parent theme to `android:Theme.Material.Light`, etc). However, upon running the app, it gives the error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMap()' on a null object reference
        at com.me.myapp.MyActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(MyActivity.java:300)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:833)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:483)
        at android.support.v13.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:447)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5463)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2560)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17430)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2001)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1166)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1054)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5779)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I decided to go through the patch again, this time changing one thing at a time. I found that if I changed the line `targetSdkVersion 20` to `targetSdkVersion 21`, the app would crash with the same `NullPointerException` as above. However, leaving the `targetSdkVersion` at 20 didn't cause an error, and the app works like I expected (including material design).

I understand that `getMap()` can return `null`, I'm just a little confused as to why it only seems to happen when `targetSdkVersion` is 21.

Has anyone else come across this? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I've since moved away from the PlaceholderFragment, but the issue persists.

Here's the relevant code from my onCreateView:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap(); // Causes NPE
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your `MyActivity.PlaceholderFragment`s `onCreateView()` method pleas? The NPE occurs at line 300 of that class.

Comment: Which version of Google Play Services you are using?

Comment: In my build.gradle: `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71'`

Answer (score 0):

You class must extend FragmentActivity , And change tag map1 to SupportMapFragment

```
YourActivity yourActivity = (YourActivity)getActivity();
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)yourActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myFriendsMapFragment);
    map = mapFragment.getMap();
```